# Python-requests 'verify' PyCurl equivalent

Tags: python-requests, ssl-certificate, pycurl

Normally when I use `requests` module I used to pass the certificate path in `verify` parameter:

```py
requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify='C:/Users/.../ca.crt', proxies=proxies)
```

But in other framework using `pycurl` inside I want to do the same.
I tried to add some options, but haven't succeeded yet:

```py
curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, 'C:/Users/.../ca.crt')
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1)
```

Comment: http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html#transfer-related-issues